# PHP - Echoing out dates from query resultset

Tags: php, sql-server, coldfusion

New to PHP; coming from a background in ColdFusion. I'm setting up a PHP 7 test page where I connect to a SQL Server DB, execute a select query, and echo out the query results in a loop. It's all working fine, except that I get nothing on screen if I try to echo out a column of type "datetime" or type "date". Do these require some kind of date formatting function to be applied before they can be echoed?

Also, for anyone else with a ColdFusion background, I've noticed PHP is somewhat cumbersome in comparison to CF when it comes to executing and outputting queries. Any tricks for making it easier? Any PHP framework particular good for this?

```
<?php
// First attempt at SQL query. Note that MSSQL_CONNECT is removed in PHP 7; need to use sqlsrv_connect
$serverName = "localhost";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"somedb", "UID"=>"someid", "PWD"=>"somepassword");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$sql = "SELECT top 10 * from tQandCDownloads order by downloadId desc";

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
echo "<br><br>";

$qry = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($qry === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $qry, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['downloadId'].", ".$row['fileName'].", ".$row['fileType'].", ".$row['downloadDate']."<br />";
}
//Remove downloadDate from above and results echo out as expected. But leave it in, and nothing echoes out to screen. Datatype is "datetime". Same thing happens with another column of type "date".
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $qry);
?>
```

Comment: I don't know how sql server store date or how sql driver retrive them, but you can var_dump($row['downloadDate']); to see the type and value.
for framework. CE3 is very light and simple framework, for me laravel and Yii2 are very good.

Comment: var_dump is no good for what I'm ultimately trying to do, which is to display a query's results as a user would want to read them on a web page. I've discovered that those columns can't be echoed because they're being treated as date objects rather than strings. Each date object has a "date" property that is a string, but I'm still unable to echo out that property. I've tried using "$row['forDate']['date']". If I can't access the property directly, I'd think the object would have some kind of "getDateString" function...

Comment: I meant var_dump for you to debug

Answer (score 3):

Okay, yes, it looks like the "date" property of the datetime object isn't meant to be accessed directly. Instead, need to call the correct method to get and display the date, which looks like it's the "format()" method. Changed my while loop to the below, and now everything is echoing out:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $qry, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['downloadId'].", ".$row['fileName'].", ".$row['downloadDate']->format('Y-m-d').", ".$row['fileType'].", ".$row['forDate']->format('Y-m-d')."<br />";
}
```

By the way, using dBug.php was how I figured out that the query column values for those two columns were objects. Mimics cfdump, which is one of my favorite Coldfusion tags. https://github.com/ospinto/dBug. I "dumped" each row in the query this way:

```
include_once("dBug.php");

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $qry, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    new dBug($row);
}
```

Comment: Always good to know the cfdump equivalent in other languages!